# How to move the origin of an Android View into its center?

Tags: java, android, view, coordinates

I made an own Joystick-View and now I have to calculate the distance between the point the user is dragging to and the center of the view. 
This would be much easier if I can translate the origin of the view from the left top (actual origin) to the center (new origin)!

Does anyone know how to do this?

*My View, schematic:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your view is an ImageView, change the imageView.scaleType to ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER.